# JPA JPQL IN clause: How to use IN clause in JPA?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

```
@Query("SELECT al FROM Customer al WHERE al.companyCode = ?1 AND al.fileCode IN ?2")
```

List findallByGroup(int CompanyCode, String groups);

Or

```
@Query("SELECT al FROM Customer al WHERE al.companyCode = :CompanyCode AND al.fileCode IN :groups")

List<Customer> findallByGroup(@Param("CompanyCode") int CompanyCode,@Param("groups") List<BigInteger> groups);
```

OR

```
@Query("SELECT al FROM Customer al WHERE al.companyCode = :CompanyCode AND al.fileCode IN (:groups)")

List<Customer> findallByGroup(@Param("CompanyCode") int CompanyCode,@Param("groups") List<BigInteger> groups);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
findAllByCompanyCodeAndFileCodeIn(int CompanyCode, List<String> groups)
```

You don't need `@Query`. Spring data can understand the query from method name. Use the above method.

Comment: thank you for help. It is done. But i was change something like "List<BigInteger>"  Not  List<"String">

Comment: Somehow it's failing for me, end of method it's creating select query as follows `select*from tab where name = ('ab', 'bc')` which is terribly wrong for mysql. Any workaround for this? @pvpkiran

Comment: My column name is  @Id
    @Column(name="product_id")
    private Long productId;Tried  @Query("select p FROM table_name p where p.productId IN (:productId)")
    List<ProductMetrics> findAllByProductIdIn(List<Long> productId); and this
    List<ProductMetrics> findAllByProductIdIn(List<Long> productId);  Both are not working.. Can you please suggest

Answer (score 1):

Not directly related to OP's specific query, but relevant to JPA IN clause in general:

Contrary to pvpkiran's answer, if you are doing anything other than SELECT queries (e.g. DELETE, UPDATE), it may be much more efficient to use `@Query`:

```
@Modifying
@Query("DELETE from Customer al where al.fileCode in :groups")
deleteByFileCodeIn(@Param("groups") List<String> groups)
```

instead of relying on Spring JPA's query method:

```
deleteByFileCodeIn(List<String> groups) // avoid this
```

---

Reason:

Spring JPA query method's default implementation of the IN clause is inefficient. Underneath the hood, it will 1. first select all records that match the IN criteria, then 2. execute a DELETE statement for **each** record found.

```
select customer.id as id,... from customer where customer.file_code in (?,?,?,...)
delete from customer where id=?
delete from customer where id=?
delete from customer where id=?
...
```

This means that if there are 1000 matching records, it will generate and execute 1000 delete statements -- instead of a single DELETE...IN statement which is what's usually intended.

By using `@Query` for IN clauses, you can override Spring JPA's default implementation and dictate a more efficient query to use instead. In my own testing this has resulted in 10x improvement in response time for large (>3K) datasets.

One caveat is that depending on the database, there may be limitations in the number of parameters that can be used in the IN clause. This can be overcome by [partitioning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40462567/9425556) the List.

Comment: Why am I getting this error with the above approach? the groups parameter is not empty. [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter not bound : groups; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter not bound : groups]

Comment: Hi @CuriousCurie would you be able to provide any code sample of what you tried?